# Check if li has particular class based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to check if particular `li` has `active class` with it . This is my HTML in bootstrap code:

```js
if ($("#monthly").hasClass("active")) {
  alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li role="presentation" id="monthly" class="active"><a href="#monthly_mship" class="text-uppercase" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> MONTHLY</a></li>
</ul>
```

Somehow its not working. Please help me with this.

**Edit**: Let me rephrahse the question in a way that this li comes in nav-tabs so it gets active class on click .

Comment: The code you've shown works fine - as you can see from the snippet I edited in to your question. Check the console for errors, and make sure you're running your jQuery code in a document.ready event handler

Comment: wrap your code in `$(function(){  /*code here*/ });` so it will wait until the DOM is loaded

Answer (score 2):

Here is quote from [learn.jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

So, make sure your code is inside:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    if ($("#monthly").hasClass("active")) {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

Or shorthand for previous:

```
$( function() {
    if ($("#monthly").hasClass("active")) {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```